# How to destroy a Quori Monolith?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, eberron

My players wish to sabotage or destroy Quori Monoliths in Khorvaire.

Do you have any experiences in that kind of scenario?

I've already hinted that Kalashtar know a way.

Are the monoliths described in any official book well?

What are they like?

What variations have you used on them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per *Secrets of Sarlona*,

> Monolith shells are designed to contain the blast of
>   a detonating core. The shell's two inner and outer layers
>   have 3 feet of space between them. Each layer is nearly 2
>   feet thick, with hardness 20 and 1,440 hit points per 10-
>   foot-square section.
>
> The core has hardness 10 and 600 hit points. If a
>   monolith's core is broken or shut down, the monolith
>   and all its subsidiary utilities cease functioning. When
>   a core is improperly tampered with, it can explode. It
>   might also explode (50% chance, takes 2d6 rounds) if it
>   takes half its hit points in damage. This explosion deals
>   20d6 points of damage to all creatures inside the shell
>   (Reflex DC 25 half).

*Secrets of Sarlona* also provides the Explosive Pack on page 138.  They allow you to set a minute timer on alchemical explosives that can do up to 10d6 pts of damage (up to three times this vs structures with an appropriate  Profession: Siege Engineer check).  Set up a handful of these, and you can make relatively swift work of the core, at least, with it's much lower hardness and HP.  If a kalashtar strike team *was* to go after a monolith, I suspect it would look an awful lot like the Endor raid from *Return of the Jedi*.  Ambush optional, of course.

Alternatively, you can use a Psicraft check, DC 35, to start a self-destruct on a 10-minute timer (as a full-round action).  On a nat-1, you have the 2d6 rounds to run like hell.

A DC 35 Psicraft check that takes *1 minute* can be attempted to try to **halt** a self destruct, as well.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the [Quori Monolith](https://sites.google.com/site/eberronpathfinder/conversion-info/magical-items/artifacts/quori-monolith) that someone linked to in the comments is accurate, critically that

> These towers ... stand anywhere between 250 to 500 feet tall with a diameter between 100 to 120 feet wide. While the walls of a Quori Monolith are 10 feet thick and the material is psionically reinforced (hardness 30, 1,440 hp per section), ...
>
> ... the base is always ringed with eight, equally spaced open archways ...

and

> In order access any of the Quori Monolith's abilities, someone must be access the Quori Monolith Control System at the top of the tower and make a Use Magic Device check. ... Any result of a natural 1 on the Use Magic Device check, except to activate it, results the immediate some of all effects and starts a self-destruct sequence.

## Hit it with a stick

There are rules in place for damaging objects; if you hit a monument with a big enough stick (to overcome its impressive hardness) for long enough (to remove each section's remarkable number of HP), it'll come tumbling down. If there are 8 archways, there are 8 solid bits between the arches; determine how many can be removed before the tower simply falls over (I'd suggest 3).

## Hit it with (a) magic (stick)

[Disintegrate](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/disintegrate.htm) or [Psionic Disintegrate](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/disintegratePsionic.htm) can both remove significant portions of a building in short order; a couple of castings should be enough to remove enough of the base to cause the tower to tumble.

[Shatter](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/shatter.htm) is not, strictly, a viable option (the tower is far too heavy), but you may rule that individual portions of the tower can be targeted individually.

... or sunder a fully-charged [Staff of the Magi](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/artifacts.htm#staffoftheMagi), but that's even more expensive ...

## Press the Self-Destruct Button

### Option A

The tower has a built-in self-destruct function: roll a nat-1 on a "do something" attempt. Have someone keep trying to "do stuff" until they roll a nat-1.

### Option B

Intentionally triggering the self-destruct appears to have a UMD DC of 35.

### Catch

Of course, either of these options "automatically alerts any quori within 10 miles", so there might be a fight to prevent the quori from saving their tower.

## Move It

Put a [Portable Hole](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#portableHole) into a [Bag of Holding](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#bagofHolding) (or vice-versa) and rule that the result destroys the tower or sucks it into the Astral Plane.

## All of that is irrelevant

You're the GM; the towers are exactly as easy to destroy as you want them to be.

Is there a McGuffin of Monolith Destruction (or re-programming) that the players need to find? Build a quest to acquire it.

Are the towers well-guarded? Build a giant melee for the PCs to overcome as they chip away at the tower.

Does the self-destruct Summon defenders? Build a "hold this position for X time" encounter, possibly with an element of chance in when, exactly, the tower destroys itself (be *very* careful with this; the PCs are likely to be *very* weak when the tower goes pop).

If this is something that the PCs want to do, you're in a **great** position: they've already given you a hook for the next leg of their adventure. With just a little bit of prodding, they can even be conned into telling you what kind of leg that should be.